# Libcurl returns "failure when receiving data from peer" in C code

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm writing a C program which uses libcurl to send HTTP POST requests. Using these two methods below, I am able to upload two different files at different timings. I am able to do it in Windows 7 and somehow when it is run in Windows XP SP3, it will return me an error :

> failure when receiving data from peer.

```
void sendFile()
{
    struct curl_httppost *post=NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *last=NULL;
    CURL *curlfile;
    CURLcode response;

    // Get a curl handle
    curlfile = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curlhash, CURLOPT_URL, URL);

    curl_formadd(&post, &last,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file1",
        CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "C:\\file1.txt",
        CURLFORM_END
        );

    curl_easy_setopt(curlfile, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);

    response = curl_easy_perform(curlfile);
    curl_formfree(post);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlfile);
}


void sendFileTwo()
{
    CURL *curlpost;
    CURLcode response;
    struct curl_httppost *post=NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *last=NULL;

    // Get a curl handle
    curlpost = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curlpost, CURLOPT_URL, URL);

    curl_formadd(&post, &last,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "File2", 
        CURLFORM_FILE, "C:\\file2.txt", 
        CURLFORM_END
        );

    curl_easy_setopt(curlpost, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);
    response = curl_easy_perform(curlpost);
    curl_formfree(post);
}
```

Comment: Could you post more information about the error after using curl_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true) ?

Comment: Hi this is what I got when I enabled verbose,
* Recv failure: Connection was aborted
* Closing connection #0
* Failure when receiving data from peer

Comment: In that case, I would check the firewall on WinXP or check user privileges.

Comment: The firewall has been turned off and Im running as Administrator

Comment: I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with Curl since the code runs on windows7, just to be sure, the file is not too big, is it?

Comment: The first file is around 2KB, the second file is 5MB. Could the file size be a problem? Or is there another way to send big files?

Comment: Were you able to send the 2KB file? That would enable to see if connection is setup properly. Size , we can discuss later

Comment: Yes I am able to send that 2kb file

Comment: could it be a timeout problem? or just drops connection instantly?